# Q-binomials at roots of unity

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, q-analogs, roots-of-unity

As the title says, given a general $q$-binomial $\binom{n}{k}_q$,
is there some general result regarding its value at a root of unity, $q = \exp(2\pi i r/N)$?

Comment: Cyclic sieving gives some values. See [Theorem 1.1](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~stant001/PAPERS/cycsieveafterfinal.pdf).

Comment: @JohnMachacek: Right - this is actually the reason I am asking the question - for an application with CSP. My problem does not fall into the classical cases in the text you are referring to, unfortunately.

Comment: I figure you may be aware, but perhaps the comment will be interesting and relevant to others. It's an interesting question. I am not sure what can be said about other cases.

Comment: Is the $q$-Lucas theorem (see, eg. Lemma 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.1020.pdf) of any help?

Comment: A partial answer is in Theorem 2.5 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/qmahler1.pdf, although I see that the previous comment covers the same cases.

Comment: You can put $q=\exp(2\pi ir/N)$ in the $q$-binomial theorem (say as stated in equation (1.87) of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, second ed.) and equate coefficients of $x^k$ to get an answer. A special case is Exercise 1.98.

Comment: To give credit where credit is due, the $q$-Lucas theorem was first published, as far as I know, by Gloria Olive, *Generalized powers*, Amer. Math. Monthly 72 (1965), 619–625, equation (1.2.4). (The proof, which is not difficult, is apparently in her 1963 Ph.D.  thesis, which I have not seen.) The theorem has been rediscovered many times since then, but I have not come across any earlier occurrence of it.

Comment: @IraGessel Is there a generalization of the q-Lucas theorem that does not assume a primitive root of unity?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I don't think so, but every root of unity is a primitive root of unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the canonical answer is the [q-Lucas theorem,](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/q-analogues.htm#prelimQanaloguesQLucas) as pointed out in the comments.

This was proved in
*Olive, Gloria*, [**Generalized powers**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2313851), Am. Math. Mon. 72, 619-627 (1965). [ZBL0215.07003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0215.07003).